# Convert SourceData to Range

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

When i call SourceData on PivotTable  i get an String :

```
MsgBox  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").SourceData
```

The retuen is "'Sheet1'!L18C1:L1471C23"

I would like to tranform this string for a RANGE but did not working !

```
Sheet = Split(Source, "'")(1)
adress = Split(Source, "'")(2)
adress = Right(adress, Len(adress) - 1)
Cell1 = Split(adress, ":")(0)
Cell2 = Split(adress, ":")(1)
Debug.Print "Sheet : " & Sheet
Debug.Print "Cell1 : " & Cell1
Debug.Print "Cell2 : " & Cell2

Debug.Print Worksheets(Sheet).Range(Cell1).Value
```

Debug windows

> Sheet : Sheet1
>
> Cell1 : L18C1
>
> Cell2 : L1471C23

**"Execution error 1004".**

Thanks

Comment: That looks like R1C1 local notation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code can be simplified a bit.  Also, this based off an English (American) version of VBA.  You should be able to modify it for the "L1C1" notion.  Last bit, there's probably other ways to solve your problem, this is just how I was able to do it.

```
Sub test1()
Dim source As String

Dim pivotData As String
Dim pivotRanage As Range

pivotData = "'Sheet1'!R29C15:R200C24"

Set pivotRange = Range(Application.ConvertFormula(pivotData, xlR1C1, xlA1))

Debug.Print pivotRange.Item(1, 1).Value

End Sub
```

In a nutshell, it converts your string in to a range.  Here is the documentation on the ConvertFormlua function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.convertformula) but in a nutshell, it takes a string and makes it a range.  Then, using that range it's simple to get the first item.

Hope that helps!