# How to extract pivot table data source range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a pivot table using the data in another sheet.  My pivot table is working fine.  When ever there is a data change when I refresh the table its captured correctly.

I tried to access the source data details for this pivot table using vba. By using the following code

```
Set PT = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Debug.Print PT.SourceData
```

It gave me the result

> Data!C1:C6

It gave the sheet name properly but not the data range.  Where am I going wrong.

Is there any other alternative available to get the source data details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely that is R1C1 notation: Column 1 to Column 6.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043341/convert-sourcedata-to-range

Comment: @BigBen  -  Thanks for your comment.  My issue here is its not giving the correct source data range.  My pivot is based on Data!a1: j752.  Even I tried with the Pivotcache, its also giving the same wrong reference.  But my pivot is intact and its refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You're pulling the R1C1 reference. That can be changed with `application.convertformula`.  Note that because you're using the entire column, it would make sense to reduce the scope of range within the sheet's `usedrange` area.See below how it would work.

```
   Set PT = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
   Set rngSourse = Range(Application.ConvertFormula(pt.SourceData, xlR1C1, xlA1))
   debug.print rngSourse.address
   Set WSsource = rngSourse.Worksheet
   Set rngSourse = Intersect(WSsource.UsedRange, rngSourse) 'now it's only the used 
   debug.print rngSourse.address
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My issue here is its not giving the correct source data range.  My pivot is based on Data!a1: j752.  Even I tried with the Pivotcache, its also giving the same wrong reference.  But my pivot is intact and its refreshing.

Comment: What's the reference? Is it refreshed? The vba code above will return the data range. Start with a fresh spreadsheed of 3 columns and make a quick pivot. You'll see it reference your original data.